# Matching "tags" and "text" with regex

Tags: c#, regex

I have a custom tag in an (html) text. From this custom tag I only need it's single specific attribute.
Needed is:

A match on text that is not a custom tag (including regular html tags).(named: text)

A match on the custom tag (mytag)and a match on the the attribute(tagattribute)

I can match the tag like so:

```
(?<mytag><my-tag\ data-tag='(?<TagAttribute>.*?)'>.*?</my-tag>)
```

if "split" the my sample with this regex I get all the parts I need:

```
<p>some text<my-tag data-tag='first'>in the tag</my-tag></p> stuff in between<my-tag data-tag='second'>in the second tag </my-tag>after the tags
```

[image: result:]

How do I combine it with something like this that captures anything up to the start of a new my-tag :

```
(?<text>((.(?!<my-tag))*(.)))
```

so that when I call NextMatch I either receive a "text" or a "mytag" and "tagattribute".

I use the [Regulator](http://sourceforge.net/projects/regulator/%22Regulator%22) and this unit test to see what C# regex makes of it

```
 [TestMethod]
 public void RegExTokenizerTest()
 {
    //arrange
    const string expression =
        @"(?<TemplateTag><my-tag\ data-tag='(?<TagAttribute>.*?)'>.*?</my-tag>)";
    const string target =
        @"<p>some text<my-tag data-tag='first'>in the tag</my-tag></p> stuff in between<my-tag data-tag='second'>in the second tag </my-tag>after the tags";
     Regex regex = 
         new Regex(
            expression,
            RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | 
            RegexOptions.CultureInvariant |
            RegexOptions.Multiline
     );
     // act

     Match match = regex.Match(target);
     while (match.Success)
     {
         ProcessMatches(match.Captures);
         match.NextMatch();
      }

      // assert
      // ...
  }
```

---

#### Got 'm

All i needed was an "|" (or)

```
(?<TemplateTag><my-tag\ data-tag='(?<TagAttribute>.*?)'>.*?</my-tag>)|(?<text>((.(?!<my-tag))*(.)))
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking for. Can you give an example (or more if you know possible complications) of what you are expecting?

Comment: i would recommend an xml/html parser instead. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: @Jerry yesterday somebody posted an answer/solution direction combining in an "or" a capturing match with a non capturing match. But the answer is gone (!?). If that was you I would like to give you some points for sending me in right direction

Comment: @k.c. Nope, but I could try contacting the person if you want; and I believe you can improve the regex performance-wise by a few times. Though I'm still not entirely sure what you were looking for.

Comment: @Jerry: we use a WYSIWYG html editor for document templates. The user can place "my-tag"'s. We replace the my-tag's with data in the final document. The template parser needs to separate "regular" html and "my-tag" html. I'm sure a real could optimize the regex further, but for the moment we are impressed with the speed as it is.

Comment: @DanielA.White : I had a look at the post you recommended, quite funny and probably true. Luckily we are NOT trying to parse generic HTML. We are trying to locate our own, well defined tags from in between random text (which happens to be HTML-ish)